# Android H.263 or H.264 file?

Tags: android, mime-types, video-encoding

Is there a way to find the codec difference for a video file on Android? I need to find out if the file is encoded as H.263 or as H.264? The mime type is always video/3gp, so that's not useful.

I read something about magic cookies, but I cannot find the magic cookie format for H.263 encoded files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for meta-data information of file.
Try:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE
```

It should display the metadata information just after the Input #0 tag.